# How to Validate a Html select Element with Laravel 5?

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.1

I've got a section list in my viewlike this:

```
        <select name="departments">
                        <option value="1">support 1</option>
                        <option value="2">support 2</option>               
         </select>
```

Now I would like to check if the *selected option value* is in my database, so users cannot sent an incorrect number of support department.

How can I access the "value" in my validator?

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'how to access the value?!' => 'required|exists:departments,id',
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a misunderstanding of what's going on. It's not the value you need to access, you need to tie it into the name of the element. Let's see what that looks like:

```
'departments' => 'required|exists:departments,id'
```

This will make sure the selected value exists in the `departments` table on the `id` column.